# Perl confusion between variables

Tags: perl

I have the following code

```
my $content = $response->content;
$content =~ /username=([\s\S]+?)&/;
my $username = $1;
print $username; #Prints the text
```

lets say I want to do this again but for different text

for example

```
$content =~ /rank=([\s\S]+?)&/;
my $rank = $1;
print $rank; #Prints the username text
```

do I have to change $1 to something else?

Comment: Is the `/rank=([\s\S]+?)&/` bit definitely matching something?

Comment: I think you should always use `$1` in combination with an `if` statement on the match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my $content = $response->content;
$content =~ /username=([\s\S]+?)&/;
my $username = $1;
print $username; #Prints the text

$content =~ /rank=([\s\S]+?)&/;

#if the above regex does not match, $1 remains set to the previous $1

my $rank = $1;
print $rank; #Prints the username text
```

It would be safer something like:

```
if ($content =~ /rank=([\s\S]+?)&/){
    my $rank = $1;
}
```

Or, more elegantly:

```
my ($rank) = $content =~ /rank=([\s\S]+?)&/;
print "\n rank:$rank" if defined $rank; #Prints the username text
```

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to change it. $1 is not preserved after a match, however it may retain its value if the match attempt fails. The rank might not be matching your pattern. Try this to make sure:

```
my ($rank) = ($content =~ /rank=([\s\S]+?)&/);
die("rankkk") if not defined $rank;
```

Comment: Which doesn't explain why the original poster is getting the username text back :-)

Comment: You are right, when you say " $1 ... will have a new value after each match". The problem is, when the second expression does not match, then `$1` will have the old value. It is **not** initialized before each regex.

Comment: @perreal: The value of `$1` *is* preserved. A successful match will modify it but an unsuccessful one will leave it *unchanged*.

Comment: An unsuccessful match is not a match in my dictionary :)

Comment: So what do you mean by *`$1` is not preserved after a match*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question about `$1` has been answered already. Here is a simpler version of your regexp:

```
/rank=(.+?)&/
```

By writing `[\s\S]` you are combining two character classes that are complement sets of each other. So, `[\s\S]` can be replaced by `.` which matches any character except newline.

If the name and rank information in your text spans multiple lines you can use the s modifier, which makes `.` match \n too.

```
/rank=(.+?)&/s
```